# What are the pros and cons of multiple rows of POLYGON vs one MULTIPOLYGON field?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, postgis

So for the first time I'm gonna do a project that involves maps and layers on top of maps which have many points and many polygons on them.

I have the tendency to create separate tables for points and polygons and then create many-to-many relationships between them and the layers table. If I do that I end up with 5 tables: `points`, `polygons`, `layers`, `layers_points` and `layers_polygons`.

However, I see PostGIS also offers types called `MULTIPOINT` and `MULTIPOLYGON`. If I use those types then I could put it all in the `layers` table. I guess that would make queries faster, because I need less joins. However, I'm not sure if later I might regret it, if it means that working with the individual points and polygons becomes impossible. I'm not even sure yet if it will be necessary to work perform calculations on the individual points and polygons, but it would be nice to know whether that's possible or not in both approaches.

So basically I'm asking, what the pros and cons are of these different approaches?

Comment: Try cross posting on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ where you will get more GIS expert views.

Comment: I don't have an answer but something to consider: Each geometry column will need an assigned geometry type. You can't mix and match inside this column. Multipoint and Multipolygon are geometry types that allow more than one feature to exist in a single record (ArcMap has these feature types too). In order to use the `layers` table, you will need to have a column for every geometry type you would like to include.

Comment: @MichaelMarkieta that restriction applied on Postgis 1.x. Version 2.x has no such limitation. You can enforce a geometry type via checks but it's entirely optional

Comment: FYI - [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html) is available to query the individual geometries from a multi, so it is possible to go backwards. You could use that for an occasional fix, but if you are constantly changing individual geometries within a group then you may be better avoiding multipart geometries.

Comment: @amenadiel thanks! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you would consider using multipolygons to represent entities that have disjoint surfaces (for example, the geometry of Alaska) or other topologies that you can't represent as polygons. The key here is that a single entity needs to be expressed with a multipolygon

What you *wouldn't do* is group *unrelated* polygons into a multipolygon, because you won't be able to perform queries at a child polygon level, unless you extract the rings into another geometry. If the polygons are unrelated, chances are you will need to query them individually. Even if they share a layer, you can manage that relation with business logic without merging them as they aren't representing the same entity.

Keep in mind that geometry tools in the frontend won't necesarilly treat multipolygons as a valid geometry or a multi object. Algorithms of point-in-polygon that looks like your use case, won't necesarilly work when checking if a point is contained in a multipolygon.

Tools like Wicket.js (transform from/to WKT/geojson/native objects) don't support multipolygons. Google maps api v3 doesn't support multipolygons except for the data layer (but you can't operate on the data layer as you would on a polygon feature). Turf.js has operations that would run on a Featurecollection containing several polygons, yet not over a multipolygon.

Without knowing your exact use case, that's the best I can tell you, and **TL/DR: keep your polygons as they are**.